# Are Azure VMs or their user accounts locked after too much activity/uploads on MSDN Premium subscription accounts?

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine

I have created an Azure VM for the purpose of testing a new installation process for my software. The VM is using Windows 10 Preview.

Yesterday I uploaded an ISO file which contained our software plus installers for SQL Server Express (various editions). (About 1.8 gb)

I ran our custom setup program which installs SQL express, restores a new user database, adds firewall exceptions etc. etc.

This morning I cannot RDP into that VM. The connection is made, but when I attempt to login, I am simply returned to the Windows Security Dialog, with the message "Your credentials did not work..."

I know I am typing the password correctly, I have double checked things like typos in the user name and password, Caps Lock is not on ;-) and so on.

This happened to a VM I had set up last week too, after a similar test and after attempting various options including resetting credentials using Powershell ([found here](http://ttp://blogs.technet.com/b/keithmayer/archive/2014/04/03/microsoft-azure-virtual-machines-reset-forgotten-admin-password-with-windows-powershell.aspx)) I accepted that I must have forgotten the password or done something wrong, so I started again.

Now the same things has happened I am wondering if that level of activity (uploading 1.8gb then running a setup which retrieved and installed .Net runtime 3.5) on an Azure VM that runs under an MSDN Premium subscription Azure account, caused the user account to be locked out for a period of time - have I hit some limit of uploads to that machine or activity or some other limit I'm not aware of?

Comment: I understand the votes to close as off topic as this is not really programming related, but bear in mind the Azure support site does point people here along with MSDN forums, for support. Possibly a problem for this sort of issue.

Comment: Closes don't necessarily shut the question down. They can also forward the question to a different forum (E.g., superuser or serverfault) where people are more likely to have an answer. :)

Comment: Agreed with Greg - this is a question for ServerFault, not StackOverflow.

Comment: Happy to send this to ServerFault. How?

Comment: If enough people with appropriate rep on the site see it and close it, it'll move to server fault automatically. You can always just log in and ask it there yourself as well. :) (May as well, usually if something's going to get closed quickly, it would already be closed)